# I encountered an error that "authentication mode= windows" error .

Tags: asp.net

Error  :

> It is an error to use a section registered as
>   allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This
>   error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an
>   application in IIS.

My error is above. How to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure the application in IIS.

IIS7 and IIS6  instructions: http://www.affiliatewiz.com/support/appstartpoint.asp

More complete IIS7 instructions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763173.aspx

And more complete IIS5/IIS6 instructions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwk103ab.aspx

Technically this crosses the line between programmer and Server Admin duties, but as a .NET web developer, you do need to know that any web site or web app you create in Visual Studio needs to be set up as its own IIS Applicaiton on the web server it's deployed to.

There's a lot of good-to-know info here, particularly if you're doing it all on your own, or the server admins aren't familiar with the relationship between IIS apps and .NET web apps.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hy1xzbw.aspx

(It's not all that uncommon for admins to not know what we need)

Answer (score 1):

Either more the registration to the appropriate place or correctly configure your virtual directory as an application in IIS.